# Not Able change parsing schema at run time in oracle apex 5

Tags: oracle12c, oracle-apex-5

I am using `Oracle apex 5`,`oracle database 12c`

I have successfully configured `oracle apex 5` with `oracle DB 12c`.

I have created `authentication scheme` using database table,that Authentication scheme worked successfully.

But my requirement is - Each user has to be connect to its own `schema`
(eg.user1 = HR; user2 = SCOTT) 
with in same application.

Shortly, application must run on `multiple schemas` at `run time`.

But I am not able to get that,I have tried below stuff -

current parsing schema is 'SCOTT' try to change it using -

1. apex_application.g_flow_owner := 'HR'; --Failed
2. ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = 'HR'; --Failed

I don't understand what to do,Please some body help me for solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, the `apex_application.g_flow_owner := 'HR';` command should do the trick but you have to place it in **shared components > security > security attributes> database session > Initialization PL/SQL Code**

Edit: First of all having a schema for each user that logs into the application i do not think is the best approach. Just think that every modification has to be done to all the schemas. I suggest you take a look at [Virtual Private Database](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/vpd.htm) (VPD) it can help you to control data access.

But if you still want to try changing the schema i think you can do it like this. Create two processes for each page in your application; one at **On Load Before Header** and one at **On Submit**. This process should contain something like this:

```
BEGIN
if :APP_USER='SCOTT' THEN
apex_application.g_flow_owner := 'SCOTT';
ELSE
apex_application.g_flow_owner := 'HR';
END IF
END;
```

Like this when Scott loads a page the schema is changed to SCOTT and he sees data from his schema. When HR loads a page the schema is changed to HR and he sees his data. Same thing when they submit a page; the schema first changes and then you do the other operations.

This second idea is not bullet proof and that's why i advise you to rethink what you want to do.

Edit2: In component view simply click on the plus sign on "Processes" to add a process and in the wizard select "On Submit - Before Computations and Validations" for the Point option. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer,that working fine, but another issue get raised,issues is suppose first user login with 'SCOTT'(default schema) and second user login with 'HR'(default schema) ,After login second user if first user get refresh his screen then it connect with latest login HR schema instead of SCOTT schema. Hope you understand and please try to solution it.

Comment: I don't have where to test this so can you please help me understand this better by performing this test. 
When Scott logs in he get one session id, lets say id 1111, when Hr logs in he(hr) gets session id 2222. What happens when Scott refreshes the page? Does he keeps his session id 1111 or is it changed?

Comment: he keeps his session id 1111 instead of others, that the issue session id not changed!

Comment: Cristian_I,can you tell me where "On Submit" Process create?

Comment: In designer mode go on your page and in the left side select the 3rd tab called "Processing" and there on "After Submit" right click and create process.
If you are on component view simply click on the plus sign on "Processes" to add a process and in the wizard select "On Submit - Before Computations and Validations" for the Point option.

Comment: there is no such "On Submit - Before Computations and Validations"  option in Point options!

Comment: I have got it and made required changes but this processes not called in tabular form at sorting and searching!